# "I would like to ask you that have you"

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

Someone sent me something and then checked back with me writing:

> I would like to ask you that have you received my gift?

I myself thought this sentence was really uncommon (I have not heard it before). I discussed it with my friend and suggested that the correct way should be

> I would like to ask if/whether you have received my gift.

He said both should be okay. Google gives more than 27 000 000 results for "I would like to ask you that have you" (maybe many people are incorrect?).

Since I am not a native speaker, I cannot prove that it is wrong.

Comment: That estimated 27,000,000 hits has now gone up to 30,100,000 - almost certainly influenced by this very question. But if you try to page through them, there are [actually only 22 results](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22I+would+like+to+ask+you+that+have+you%22&start=20). You don't seem to have mentioned it, but I would think it's almost certain your friend is not a native speaker (as is obviously the case with many if not most of the 22 results that Google eventually admits to).

Comment: 30,100,000 people _can't_ be right.

Comment: Wow... I've used stack exchange sites  for  two years now  I think but I doubt  I'll  ever  understand  the  enthusiasm  for closing  relevant  questions that are  answerable and create  interesting relevant discussion. `ltt` has learned  something  useful  from  my answer and I've learned  useful  detail  from  the  excellent comments  below... but apparently  this sort of thing  must be stopped because no "specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified" (to  me there's a perfectly clear source of concern right there in the question, but never mind...)

Comment: Is this Indian English by any chance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  use of "that" in a question isn't right, and "have you" should be reversed.

---

You'd use "that" if it was a statement, not a question: "it is true that...", for example:

- I would like to **tell** you ***that*** you should have received my gift
- I would like to **show** you ***that*** you must have received my gift
- I would like to **inform** you ***that*** you  will soon have received my gift

Your example is a question, so the word needs to match the intention of the question -  indicating that this question seeks a yes or no answer:

- I would like to **ask** you ***if*** you have received my gift?
- I would like to **ask** you ***whether*** you have received my gift?

Replacing this changes the meaning of the question:

- I would like to **ask** you ***how*** you have received my gift?
- I would like to **ask** you ***when*** you have received my gift?
- I would like to **ask** you ***why*** you have received my gift?
- I would like to **ask** you ***who*** has received my gift?

Or maybe you meant more like this:

- I would like to ask you a question: have you received my gift?
- I would like to ask: have you received my gift?

Comment: All correct, except for the first sentence. It has nothing to do with the use of _that_ in a question. Rather, it has to do with the fact that the verb _ask_ with an indirect object can take either an infinitive complement (_I would like to ask you to take out the garbage_) or an embedded question complement, as here. It can't take a _that_-complement, as here; and it can't take a gerund complement, either (_*I would like to ask you staying for a few minutes_). All verbs have their own specific requirements for [complements](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/comps.pdf).

Comment: Please note @JohnLawler’s careful wording: ‘ask’ _with an indirect object_ cannot take a _that_ complement. If there is no indirect object, of course, it can: “We kindly ask that you refrain from smoking”. Also noteworthy, however, is the fact that the infinitive complement and the _that_ complement are only possible when the meaning of ‘ask’ is ‘request’ rather than ‘pose a question’. Therefore, even if the verb and auxiliary are reversed, “I would like to ask that you have received my gift” is nonsense, because it is _requesting_ someone to have already done something—which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask you that have you received my gift?

I would like to ask *(you) if you (have)* received my gift?

Comment: @ Rubric K Venison: Thanks for your reply. I know and use the same way as you wrote. I just want to ask whether the mentioned alternative (in my question) is also ok.

Comment: @ Rubric K Venison: Are you Groucho in disguise?